# PowerLine networking & Security

Tags: security, powerline-networking

I wonder if my neighbors will be able to connect into my network? How can I know or prevent this? Since with Wireless, I will have to authenticate but with powerline, I connect as if I connect directly into the router with Ethernet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most powerline devices include the same (or similar) encryption and security as Wireless.

For example, the [Belkin PowerLine AV](http://www.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=459681) has:

> Security: 128-bit AES link encryption with key management for secure powerline communications

Comment: ok, I have an [Aztech 200MBps Homeplug](http://www.aztech.com/sg/homeplug_hl110ep.html) with AC pass thru. **[here](ftp://ftp.aztech.com/support/singapore/HomePlug/HL110EP%20FAQ%20Pairing%20your%20Aztech%20HL110EP%20with%20another%20Aztech%20HL110EP.pdf)** it tells me how to "pair" the plugs. Seems like I just plug in and it will automatically sync? If thats the case, whats stopping someone from getting the same model and plugging it in? There dont seem to be any UI to set keys etc, I dont see a button tho, maybe I will look closer tmr

Comment: They are often sold in pairs with the same key pre-set on them both.

Comment: for me, they came separately ... I guess I have to sync them, whats confusing is on 1st connection, they connected automatically, I do see a small button perhaps thats the "simple connect" button. I dont see a way to verify noone else is able to connect into the network tho

Comment: Down vote because the answer does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

With most Powerline networks, the homeplugs contain security, normally a encrypted key. I have a Belkin Powerline HD Adapter and it has the ability to change the key, and then you have to manually set the new key to each adapter used in the house. This way if anyone else is using the same powerline as you, they can not access your network unless their homeplugs are manually paired.

If you look in the documentation of some homeplugs, it should state what needs to be done.

Comment: For me, the **[manual](ftp://ftp.aztech.com/support/singapore/HomePlug/HL110EP%20FAQ%20Pairing%20your%20Aztech%20HL110EP%20with%20another%20Aztech%20HL110EP.pdf)** seem to mean that its quite automatic? I just plug in and wait for it to sync, I dont seem to notice a button, will check tmr ...

Comment: Looking at the website you posted: http://www.aztech.com/sg/homeplug_hl110ep.html it states there is a "simple connect" button something may be linked to that. Or you can not change the key on the adapters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a concern in a personal house, as all circuits should be disconnected from the grid (as far as the transmitted data is concerned) by the power meters. However, in an apartment building, this is not guaranteed to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is: all traffic sent over Powerline is encrypted with 128 bit AES.

The bad news is: nearly all Powerline adapters I have seen so far are using the same standard password "HomePlugAV". A powerline network is formed by all adapters with the same password, so normally if you buy two adapters they will have the same password and see each other.

So if you want to be sure that a neighbour can not connect to your powerline network, then you should configure your adapters with an individual password. You can do this by pressing the security button (please consult the manual of your adapters). Or you can do it using a PC software.